# process.env.NODE_ENV broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I have an `.env` file in the root directory:

```
NODE_ENV='development'
```

and a file

`server.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const baseUrl = nodeEnv === 'production' ? 'https://heroku-url.herokuapp.com' : 'http://localhost:3020';
```

WHY is `nodeEnv` set to production?

Doesn't matter if I rebuild.

It seems that env is already set to development:

```
node                       

Welcome to Node.js v12.19.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
development
undefined
> console.log('a')
a
undefined
> const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;
undefined
> const baseUrl = nodeEnv === 'production' ? 'https://simplefi-server.herokuapp.com' : 'http://localhost:3021';
undefined
> console.log(baseUrl);
http://localhost:3021
```

Comment: Check whether you have `NODE_ENV` already set in your system/terminal-session. Dotenv package [doesn't modify existing variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set).

Comment: it's not. I can't seem to set it using `$env:NODE_ENV="development"`

Comment: in your terminal, run `node`, type `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`, and check what Is being printed. On your local, it should be undefined unless otherwise changed.

Comment: strange, it's `development` but the production branch is taken in the code

Comment: It's not linked to code but how node is setup in your system. I recommend changing the logic to `nodeEnv !== "production"` to check for specific value of string.

Comment: It made no difference; the environment seems correct but when serving the build directory it changes. `serve -s build`